# Storyboard override system font

Tags: ios, fonts, storyboard

Is possible change the system font with other font, and use *Text Styles* in story board with the "new system font"?

[image]

[image]

Or is possible define a custom font with styles and see it in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

in the first line of your image **tap** on '**T**' like button.

then **Custom**-> **down arrow** of *Family*

Comment: Thanks for answer, you are right but I need do it for all labels. I want know if is possible set the system font and use it without specify my custom font, size and style for every labels in my project. Is possible use ```UILabel.appearance().font = UIFont(name: "", size: 16)``` but set font size  to 16 for all labels.